# Funny behavior with numba - guvectorized functions using argmax()

Tags: vectorization, numba, argmax

Consider the following script:

```
from numba import guvectorize, u1, i8
import numpy as np

@guvectorize([(u1[:],i8)], '(n)->()')
def f(x, res):
    res = x.argmax()

x = np.array([1,2,3],dtype=np.uint8)
print(f(x))
print(x.argmax())
print(f(x))
```

When running it, I get the following:

```
4382569440205035030
2
2
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have references, so `res = ...` is not actually assigning to the output parameter, but instead rebinding the name `res`.  I believe res is pointing to uninitialized memory, which is why your first run gives a seemingly random value.

Numba works around this using the slice syntax (`[:]`) which does mutate res- you also need to declare the type as an array.  A working function is:

```
@guvectorize([(u1[:], i8[:])], '(n)->()')
def f(x, res):
    res[:] = x.argmax()
```

Comment: I had somehow managed to convince myself that the weird behavior had to do with numba in combination with argmax, but indeed something like `res = x[0]` has the same problem.